# subfloat text overflow onto the second line and remove gap between the image identifier and beginning of text

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats

I have three images that i need to show on the same horizontal level.
THe problem that iam having is that the image description that i place below is overflowing on to the second line. Moreover there is a huge space between the image identifier character and the beginning of the word.(between a) and EN-)

Here is my code

```
\begin{figure}[!h]  
  \centering  
  \subfloat[ENGINE1]{\label{fig:gull}\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/lzw.eps}}     
   \hspace{2px}
 \subfloat[ENGINE12]{\label{fig:gull}\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/wav.eps}}     
    \hspace{2px}
 \subfloat[BITMAP]{\label{fig:gull}\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/bit.eps}}  
 \caption{Systems} 
     \label{fig:bitmapVisualize}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: The `subfig` package may help you. Also, read section 1.1 "Do You Need This Package?" from the package's documentation. There are three examples that may be exactly what you need.

Comment: if i hadn't imported the subfig package i wouldn't have had this issue in the first place

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using `subfigure` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the `\subfloat` is determined by the graphic. Therefore, place the graphic inside a box of fixed width *larger* than the original graphic. Something like the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]  
  \centering  
  \subfloat[ENGINE1]{\label{fig:gull}\makebox[7em]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/lzw.eps}}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[ENGINE12]{\label{fig:gull}\makebox[7em]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/wav.eps}}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[BITMAP]{\label{fig:gull}\makebox[7em]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/bit.eps}}}
  \caption{Systems} 
  \label{fig:bitmapVisualize}
\end{figure}
```

The above places all images in a box of width `7em`, centred (by default). Modify the length to suit.

---

In `twocolumn` document mode, you should rather use `\columnwidth` as your width specifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
  \centering  
  \subfloat[ENGINE1]{\label{fig:engine1}\makebox[.3\columnwidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/lzw.eps}}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[ENGINE12]{\label{fig:engine12}\makebox[.3\columnwidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/wav.eps}}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[BITMAP]{\label{fig:bitmap}\makebox[.3\columnwidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/bit.eps}}}
  \caption{Systems} 
  \label{fig:bitmapVisualize}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If need be, you can reduce the `\subfloat` font size by issuing something like `\footnotesize` inside it (`\subfloat[\footnotesize ENGINE12]{..}`). Always keep in mind that these things should be done consistently.

Comment: Isn't it possible to remove the gap that iam talking about without increasing the gap between images ?

Comment: as you can see on the image that i posted, there is a unnecessary gap between a)  and  EN-

Comment: @user581544: As mentioned, the width of the caption is based on the width of the image. Since the images are not as wide as the sub-captions, LaTeX introduces hyphenation and breaks them into two lines/rows. The *easiest* is to enlarge the image width "technically" (not physically).

Comment: Unfortunately iam using double column format and increasing image width is not a option as it will then make the image overflow onto the next column. Is it possible to reduce the size of the caption text?

Comment: @user581544: You should then scale things based on `\columnwidth` rather than `\textwidth`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Using `\footnotesize` directly as you suggest can produce undesired results if the subfigures are to be listed in a LoF.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package instead of the `subfig` package; using the former you can easily set the width of the box reserved for the subfloat and its caption independently from the width of the actual image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
\subcaptionbox{ENGINE1\label{fig:gull4}}[.2\textwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/lzw.eps}}%
\subcaptionbox{ENGINE12\label{fig:gull5}}[.2\textwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/wav.eps}}%
\subcaptionbox{BITMAP\label{fig:gull6}}[.2\textwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{textures_data_types/bit.eps}}%  
\caption{Systems} 
\label{fig:bitmapVisualize2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an example code using the `twocolumn` document option and showing the use of `\captionsetup` command to reduce the font size for the subfigures caption:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize}% reduces font size for subfigure captions  
\subcaptionbox{ENGINE1\label{fig:gull4}}[.3333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/lzw.eps}}%
\subcaptionbox{ENGINE12\label{fig:gull5}}[.3333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/wav.eps}}%
\subcaptionbox{BITMAP\label{fig:gull6}}[.3333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{textures_data_types/bit.eps}}%  
\caption{Systems} 
\label{fig:bitmapVisualize2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]